# Añadir elemento con ID personalizado a Firebase Database desde Java

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase

estoy desarrollando una pequeña apliación y mi intención es añadir a la base de datos Firebase Database Realtime un elemento con ID personalizada.

Quisiera que la estructura de datos quedara así:

[image]

El caso es que a la hora de añadir un nuevo elemento con ***push***, se añade con un ID personalizado alfanumérico que genera automáticamente Google.

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("anuncios");

    Data data = new Data(descripcion, titulo);

    mDatabase.child("2").push().setValue(data);
```

He leído que con el ***set*** se podría hacer, ya que contiene un apartado ***data*** (información a insertar) y otro ***key*** (ID personalizada), ¡pero el IDE me dice que no se encuentra la función!

¿Alguien podría ayudarme? Muchísimas gracias y espero que vaya bien vuestro confinamiento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estas usando `.push()` despues de child, la idea seria que uses o push o `.child` para setear la clave de tu nodo

```
mDatabase.child("2").setValue(data);
```

Recorda que no es buena practica si tenes varios datos dinamicos que se deberian ir creando, por que deberias desde el cliente ir aumentando en +1 el nombre del nodo, y puede generar incosistencias cuando el usuario inicie de nuevo la app o la borre y la instale.

Es recomendable usar `push()` para generar claves únicas que no se repitan nunca (no se repiten por que la clave esta compuesta de un timestamp mas una clave alfanumerica unica)

Como estas usando Firebase realtime database y no Firestore, el `.set()` no te va a funcionar, el `.set()` funciona solo en Firestore